# htaccess: redirect from root to subfolder default language

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I trying to redirect users from my root to the default language path if is not set one. This is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

# with language
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(create) create.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(recents) index.php?lang=$1&sort=recents [L]

# original, without language
# what rules here?
```

If is not set a language I want to redirect to:

- domain.com to domain.com/en
- domain.com/foo to domain.com/en/foo
  -etc..

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a new rule for handling this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# add /en/ to URIs if missing
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/[a-z]{2}/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ en%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302,NC,NE]

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

# with language
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(create) create.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(recents) index.php?lang=$1&sort=recents [L]
```

Comment: I get a bucle redirect with this line, i cannot solve this. From: domain.com/create redirect to: domain.com/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/create and Chrome stop here the redirects